# How to CAST function in redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to convert this sql query into redshift

```
select cast(START_MINUTE * interval '1 minute'as time) from table name
```

The above one is my query. The error I get is:

> Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;

How do I make this work in Redshift?

Comment: Should work just fine. What is the error you get?

Comment: Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;

Comment: What is the data type of `start_minute`? And what is the problem you are trying to solve? Casting an `interval` to a `time` does not really make sense to me.

Comment: Can you specify hat exactly you want to achieve? There might exist an alternative way for that.

Comment: i have to run that sql query in redshift

Comment: No, I meant what output do you expect after running that query.

Comment: ?COLUMN?
06:00:00
06:00:00
04:00:00
02:00:00
02:00:00

Comment: I need to get like the above output.

Comment: Could you please provide more information about WHY you wish to do the above, and how you intend to use the result?. That might help us to provide a solution for you. For example, you might be wanting to use an `INTERVAL`, but we'd need more information to know. See also: [Redshift Datetime data types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Datetime_types.html)

Comment: That query can't be exactly reproduced on Redshift as there is no "TIME" data type. You need to include more information about what kind of data is stored in START_MINUTE and what you plan to use this for so that someone can suggest a solution. In general terms you will probably need to use the TIMESTAMP data type (which also includes a date component) and the DATEADD function.

Comment: Works fine on my redshift both as select cast(1.0::float * interval '1 minute'as time); and select cast(1::int * interval '1 minute'as time); You need to provide your source table schema and sample data, because there is clearly an issue there.